# Make a recursive function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to make a recursive function for this parameters. Function should determine the nth element of the row

```
a_0 = 1
a_k = k*a_(k-1) + 1/k
k = 1,2,3...
```

I am trying really hard to do this but i cant get a result. Please help me to do this

I came up with this but it is not a recursive function. I can not do this as a recursive function

```
let a = 1
let k = 1
let n = 3
for (let i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    a = i*a + 1/i
}
console.log(a)
```

Comment: The example doesn't seem to be valid JavaScript? Please may you update it to be a [mcve]? (Or are you using a notation my silly brain doesn't know?)

Comment: Can you please show the recursive function that you've tried to implement so far?

Comment: Create a function `a` with one input parameter `k`. It has two cases: `k = 0` returns `1` and `k > 0` returns `k*a(k-1) + 1/k`.

Comment: Please may you also clarify what this function is trying to do? I’m not very bright, so I’d like to know the purpose/goal of this function

Comment: This is homework help.  Other people are asking the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the recursive function you're looking for, it has two conditions:

- `k == 0` => `1`
- `k != 0` => `k * fn(k - 1) + 1/k`

```js
function fn(k) {
  if(k <= 0) return 1;
  return k * fn(k - 1) + 1/k;
}

console.log(fn(1));
console.log(fn(2));
console.log(fn(3));
console.log(fn(4));
```

> Note: I changed the condition of `k == 0` to `k <= 0` in the actual function so it won't stuck in an infinite loop if you pass a negative `k`

Comment: Please keep this in mind when you answer such a question [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: bro thats what i was looking for. thank you a lot